# how to write a nested case query and get correct results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a case query and need help in re-writing it to get perfect results. The current query is as follows:

```
    CASE 
WHEN MonthsRetrieved <= 6 AND MonthsRetrieved > 0 THEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt <= 6 THEN 'Fast' 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 6 AND MonthsSinceLastReceipt <= 12 THEN 'Slow' 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 12 AND MonthsSinceLastReceipt <= 18 THEN 'Very Slow' 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 18 THEN 'Dead' 
        WHEN OpeningQty = 0 THEN 'New Items' 
        WHEN QtyIssued = 0 THEN 'Non-Moving' 
    ELSE 'Fast' 
    END 
WHEN MonthsRetrieved > 6 AND MonthsRetrieved <= 12 THEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN MonthsRetrieved <= 12 THEN 'Slow' 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 12 AND MonthsSinceLastReceipt <= 18 THEN 'Very Slow' 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 18 THEN 'Dead' 
        WHEN OpeningQty = 0 THEN 'New Items' 
        WHEN QtyIssued = 0 THEN 'Non-Moving' 
    ELSE 'Slow' 
    END 
WHEN MonthsRetrieved > 12 AND MonthsRetrieved <= 18 THEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt <= 18 THEN 'Very Slow' 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 18 THEN 'Dead' 
        WHEN OpeningQty = 0 THEN 'New Items' 
        WHEN QtyIssued = 0  THEN 'Non-Moving' 
    ELSE 'Very Slow' 
    END 
WHEN MonthsRetrieved = 0 THEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt = 0 THEN 'Dead' 
        WHEN OpeningQty = 0 THEN 'New Items' 
        WHEN QtyIssued = 0 THEN 'Non-Moving' 
    ELSE 'Dead' 
    END 
WHEN MonthsRetrieved > 18 THEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 18 THEN 'Dead' 
        WHEN OpeningQty = 0 THEN 'New Items' 
        WHEN QtyIssued = 0 THEN 'Non-Moving' 
    ELSE 'Dead' 
    END 
END
```

I am getting a value in months from a formula and it is in `MonthsRetrieved`. 
Another value in months is `MonthsSinceLastReceipt`, which the months since last receipt date.
`OpeningQty` is the opening quantity at a specific date.
`QtyIssued` is the quantity issued between two dates.

The items are being classified into Fast, Slow, Very Slow, Dead, New Items, Non-Moving. The case statement is nested for each classification. I am getting results but they are not correct. I am sure I am overlooking something in the statement.

Comment: What results are you getting and why are they not correct? Can you add sample data and expected results?

Comment: Have a table with the limits. Join. Once case.

Comment: One thing I see: `when openingqty = 0 then 'New Items'` - shouldn't that be the classification IN ALL CASES when the opening quantity is 0? The way you wrote it, it will not be IN ALL CASES but only if the other "WHEN" conditions fail. Same for 'Non-Moving'.

Comment: Personally without more reference to actual data I would do a cte(common table expression) to do a series of columns for case statements for your high level and your mid level(MonthsRetrieved, MonthsSinceLastReceipt).  This way you break apart logic for reuse later.  When you are typing a similar thing over and over again in code, it probably could be more efficient.  But until you give a dataset and the expected outcome, most people can only give suggestions and not definitive answers.

Answer (score 1):

The WHEN's in a CASE are evaluated in Order.
And once one evaluates as true, what follows gets ignored.

So when you do for example :

```
CASE WHEN x >= 1 and x < 3 THEN
   CASE 
   WHEN x = 1 then 'one'
   WHEN x < 3 then 'two'
   WHEN y = 0 then 'THIS GETS NEVER EVALUATED'
   END
END
```

The 3th gets never evaluated since one of the previous checks will surely be true.

So you probably need to move those checks on OpeningQty and QtyIssued above the checks on MonthsSinceLastReceipt.

And also review how you check on MonthsSinceLastReceipt. Some of those checks will always be ignored in your current query.

I suggest creating a small mockup table with just those column names and fill that with values for each case.  Then use that table to construct a query with cases till it the results are exactly as you expect them to be.

Here's an attempt. But without knowing what the expected results should be, it's just a guess.

```
delete from TestTable;
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(0,0,0,0);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,0,0,0);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,0,0);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,6,19);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,6,13);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,6,7);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,6,3);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,12,19);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,12,13);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,12,7);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,18,19);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,18,15);
insert into TestTable (OpeningQty,QtyIssued,MonthsRetrieved,MonthsSinceLastReceipt) values(1,1,19,0);

select t.*,
CASE
WHEN OpeningQty = 0 THEN 'New Items'
WHEN QtyIssued = 0 THEN 'Non-Moving'
WHEN MonthsRetrieved = 0 THEN 'Dead'
WHEN MonthsRetrieved BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN 
    (CASE
     WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 18 THEN 'Dead'
     WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 12 THEN 'Very Slow' 
     WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 6  THEN 'Slow' 
     ELSE 'Fast' 
    END)
WHEN MonthsRetrieved BETWEEN 7 AND 12 THEN 
    (CASE 
     WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 18 THEN 'Dead'
     WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 12 THEN 'Very Slow' 
     ELSE 'Slow'
     END)
WHEN MonthsRetrieved BETWEEN 13 AND 18 THEN 
    (CASE 
     WHEN MonthsSinceLastReceipt > 18 THEN 'Dead'
     ELSE 'Very Slow' 
     END)
WHEN MonthsRetrieved >= 19 THEN 'Dead' 
END as result
from TestTable t;
```